# Solr 8.2 on OpenJDK 12 is not adding users via the API in standalone mode with security.json file

Tags: solr, basic-authentication

I've set up simple Apache Solr installation 8.2.0 and have managed to get it to run, however when I add the default security.json file it will not allow me to add users using the v1 API.  This server is in standalone mode.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
security.json location: /var/solr/data

I've added the default security.json file:

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true, 
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}, 
   "realm":"My Solr users", 
   "forwardCredentials": false 
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}], 
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"} 
}}
```

And this allows for authentication using the default solr/SolrRocks account.  I want to create a new user and remove the default user.  When I run the API command documented here:

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/basic-authentication-plugin.html

```
curl --user solr:SolrRocks http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"set-user": {"tom" : "TomIsCool"}}'
```

I get this response from Solr:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":27},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException"],
    "msg":"Failed persisting security.json to /var/solr/data/security.json",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Failed persisting security.json to /var/solr/data/security.json\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.persistConf(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:89)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandler.doEdit(SecurityConfHandler.java:134)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandler.handleRequestBody(SecurityConfHandler.java:85)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:820)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:786)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:546)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:423)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:350)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\nCaused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/solr/data/security.json\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)\n\tat java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:478)\n\tat java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:222)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SecurityConfHandlerLocal.persistConf(SecurityConfHandlerLocal.java:84)\n\t... 37 more\n",
    "code":500}}
```

There are no other serivces on this box and I can't find anything in Google or here describing this issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `/var/solr/data/security.json` is owned by a different user than what Solr runs under, and the permissions set doesn't allow the Solr user to write to it.

You can check the permissions by doing `ls -al /var/solr/data/security.json` and comparing the owning user to the user running solr. You can see the user Solr is running under by doing `ps aux | grep solr`.

Changing ownership of the file can be done by issuing a `chown` command, or changing permissions through `chmod`.

Comment: Yes this was it.  When I created the file I did it as root and not the solr user.  Thanks so much!